# Flutter Web Error. Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am making an app and drop it in the web. But when I launch it, in chrome there is a blank screen. There is my log from console in chrome:

```
Installed new service worker.
zone.dart:1339 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
at Object.ad5 (core.dart:54)
at Object.ajF (cloud_firestore_web.dart:36)
at cloud_firestore_web.dart:29
at ad0.a (async_patch.dart:316)
at ad0.$2 (async_patch.dart:341)
at Object.U (async_patch.dart:246)
at adP (main.dart:10)
at js_helper.dart:2684
at js_helper.dart:2684
at dartProgram (js_helper.dart:2684)
```

Here is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:brew_crew/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/models/user.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserClass>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also there is an index.html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <!--
        If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
        href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

        The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
        it to work correctly.

        For more details:
        * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
      -->
      <base href="/">

      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
      <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

      <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="brew_crew">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

      <title>brew_crew</title>
      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
           application. For more information, see:
           https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
      <script>
        var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
        var scriptLoaded = false;
        function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing ?? reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also if you need you can go to git repository to another files.
https://github.com/rostikro/The-app

I'm using the Flutter 2.0.2.

Comment: Do you have a `generated_plugin_registrant.dart` in your project directory ?

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your Github repo link, your index.html is missing implementations for Firebase JS entries.

Your pubspec.yaml file includes these dependancies:

```
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0+1
```

But you aren't telling your index.html to import them. The following imports will work for versions ^1.0.1 of  firebase_auth and cloud_firestore

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

Please follow along with the documentation, they put up a very nice and thorough explanation for everything regarding Firebase & Flutter specifically [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview). You also mentioned that you are using version 2.0.2 of Flutter, so please pay attention to null-safety.

Comment: Did you try these suggestions?